# laravel through relation - I'm lost

Tags: laravel, relationships

I have this very basic problem.
I have 3 models:
Author - Book - Excerpt

In *Author* I have this relation:

```
public function autoredExcerpts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Excerpt', 'author_id');
}
```

In my VIEW I want to display author info and list all excerpts from his books. I have this

```
@foreach ($author->autoredExcerpts as $xc)
<div class="box_excerpt">
{{$xc->content}}  //prints the excerpt
<span class="source">{{ $xc->book_id}}</span>  // now it prints the book's id only
</div>
@endforeach
```

**How I can print the book's name?**

In the Book model the column with name is simply 'title'

**Important:** There will be multiple excerpts from one book and in case of many authors - many books. 
I guess I need HasOneThrough relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hasManyThrough` to relate the Author to his Excerpts, and use a `belongsTo` to relate the Excerpt back to its Book:

[Has-many-through relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through) between the Author and his Books:

```
class Author extends Eloquent {

    public function excerpts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Excerpt', 'Book');
    }
```

Tell the Excerpt [who he belongs to](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-one) (assuming that each Excerpt can belong to only one Book):

```
class Excerpt extends Eloquent {

    public function book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Book');
    }
```

Now in your view:

```
@foreach ($author->excerpts as $excerpt)
  <div class="box_excerpt">

    {{ $excerpt->content }}  //prints the excerpt (assuming it's stored in 'content')
    <span class="source">{{ $excerpt->book->title }}</span>  // the book's name

  </div>
@endforeach
```

---

Just a final point on this: [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) can makes it easy on your DB too.. I don't know where you are defining `$author`, but you can pull the records for the books and excerpts at the same time, to reduce calls to the DB:

```
$author = Author::with('excerpts.book')->find($author_id);
```

Comment: not that easy. 
Every book will have multiple excerpts, not one. And the excerpts can be sourced from different books, many at a time.

Comment: it doesn't work. Maybe I need some rest. I will approach to this with fresh mind later. 
Thx

Comment: @PiotrPlebaniak just built a simple test app here, and this structure is working for me.. let me know what error you're getting and I'll try to help you... It could be that an assumption I've made about your DB structure is not correct.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it!

Comment: I have found the reason of my yesterday failure. If I change relation name from 'book' into 'sourcedBook', L5 will produce this error: at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException)

Comment: For the other relatin name 'authoredExcerpts' instead of 'excerpts' works just fine.

Comment: Ah, are you using Laravel 5 ?  I would wait a bit.. it's not stable yet.  Better to develop on 4.2 and wait for them to finish 5!